# Do something if there is a new record in database (SQL)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm programming an online card game (PHP) and I haven't got any knowledge in Javscript, Ajax, XML, etc.

Lets suppose I have a card, and I want to play that card. So I click on that card and the card is played (let's think it's on the table). But I want others players to view that I played the card without refreshing the page. I know it is possible with Ajax or jQuery, but I don't know how to use it, so let's suppose it is like this:

Mysql:
Table: Gameboard
Row - playedcard

I play the card, and it add a value to the row "playedcard"

The row has now a new record:
8Clubs

It's okay, I can see the played card because when I played it, the page refreshed, but not for the others

And I wanted to others players to see the card withouth manually refreshing... I know I can refresh only a div everysecond with Javascript, and put the php code to see if there is a new record inside that div, but it isn't professional and it may "overload" the "server"...

I was thinking something like that (obviously it is completely different, I'm just trying to explain my logic)

Ajax/jQuery code:

```
$check if_row(playedcard).newrecord = true
{
Do something
}
```

And I wanted to know if it is possible to be always checking (not refreshing that function every second), it would be like something instantly. In the moment I play a card it would immediately show to the others the card played...

Comment: If you're wanting an event to fire when something changes then you're better off looking at websockets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604210/a-facebook-like-notification-system-in-php

Comment: @BenFortune Which unfortunately for xickoh, isn't beginners territory (Despite it being easily the best solution available for real-time games)

Comment: if it is PHP I think I can hundle it, I'd just like to have a code example... Could you guys provide me a code that do something if a record is added/changed?