# Database Table structure for notification system for codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have to create a notification system in `Codeigniter`.

In this notification two types of user, One is Buyer and Second is Seller.

Buyer Buy or Review any Seller's product/order then this notification should be sent to seller.

Same is seller review to any buyer then this notification should be sent to that Buyer.

All Rating/Review and order system is working. But I have to built a notification for this.

I am little confuse on notification table structure. Can any `mysql, sql or sql-server expert` help me on this?

NOTE:- I am using below table structure for this. But I don't think this is good.

```
notification_id
user_id
module
action_type
added_by
read
read_date
```

Module is where it was performed at, and action_type is what happened (comment, deletion, added, etc). Read is if it's already been viewed, and read_date is when it was viewed.

[Click Here for reference from where I got this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604210/a-facebook-like-notification-system-in-php/3604255#3604255)

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @nody Please see my edited query.

Comment: can you elaborate the attributes with details data(usage of attributes fields).

Comment: from user_id, can you identify the user? means whether user is buyer or seller

Comment: Please see my edited query..

Comment: read my comment please

Comment: @nody Yes this is for user like buyer/seller. If buyer do anything then this for seller. and If seller do anything then this for buyer.

Comment: why do you need module column?

Comment: @nody I want to use module name for just save my codeigniter action/function name only where this notification is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
column_name

notification_id
product_id -> for which product buyer has notified
action_type -> 'comment','like'
added_by -> who gave the notification
read -> 0 or 1
read_date -> datetime
```

Comment: Hey @nody I have a new query. can you take a look? [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657394/multiple-unions-with-joins-in-mysql-using-multiple-tables)

Comment: Please [click on this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657394/multiple-unions-with-joins-in-mysql-using-multiple-tables). You will get the detail