# multiple unions with joins in mysql using multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a UNION in mysql query. This is working fine for me.

The main purpose of this query to get notification's data from multiple tables.

This is taking `0.0009 sec` time to execute. with less data.

Can any sql expert help me to improve this sql query or guide me for this sql query.

`I am not good in mysql`

```
  SELECT
        HM_notification.product_id,
        HM_products.slug,
        HM_notification.action_type,
        HM_notification.url,
        HM_notification.read_date
        FROM `HM_notification` 
            JOIN HM_customers ON HM_customers.id = HM_notification.added_by 
            JOIN HM_products ON HM_products.id = HM_notification.product_id 
            JOIN HM_reviews ON HM_reviews.product_id = HM_notification.product_id 
            WHERE HM_products.user_id=34 AND HM_notification.added_by != 34 AND action_type = 'reviews'

    UNION        

  SELECT 
        HM_notification.product_id,
        HM_products.slug,
        HM_notification.action_type,
        HM_notification.url,
        HM_notification.read_date
        FROM `HM_notification` 
            JOIN HM_customers ON HM_customers.id = HM_notification.added_by 
            JOIN HM_bid ON HM_bid.product_id = HM_notification.product_id 
            JOIN HM_products ON HM_products.id = HM_notification.product_id 
            WHERE HM_products.user_id=34 AND HM_notification.added_by != 34  AND action_type = 'newbid' OR action_type = 'editbid'

    UNION        

    SELECT 
        HM_notification.product_id,
        HM_products.slug,
        HM_notification.action_type,
        HM_notification.url,
        HM_notification.read_date
        FROM `HM_notification` 
            JOIN HM_customers ON HM_customers.id = HM_notification.added_by 
            JOIN HM_products ON HM_products.id = HM_notification.product_id 
            JOIN HM_order_items ON HM_order_items.product_id = HM_notification.product_id 
            WHERE HM_products.user_id=34 AND HM_notification.added_by != 34 AND (action_type = 'order_pending' OR action_type = 'processing' OR action_type = 'onhold' OR action_type = 'unhold' OR action_type = 'receive' OR action_type = 'addshipment' OR action_type = 'editshipment' OR action_type = 'newcomment' OR action_type = 'addshipmentcomment')

    UNION        

  SELECT 
        HM_notification.product_id,
        HM_products.slug,
        HM_notification.action_type,
        HM_notification.url,
        HM_notification.read_date
        FROM `HM_notification` 
            JOIN HM_customers ON HM_customers.id = HM_notification.added_by 
            JOIN HM_products ON HM_products.id = HM_notification.product_id 
            JOIN HM_conversation ON HM_conversation.pid = HM_notification.product_id 
            WHERE HM_products.user_id=34 AND HM_notification.added_by != 34 AND (HM_conversation.user_one != 34 || HM_conversation.user_two != 34) AND action_type = 'conversation'
```

This is a simple sql query to fetch specific url with product id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
            HM_notification.product_id,
            HM_products.slug,
            HM_notification.action_type,
            HM_notification.url,
            HM_notification.read_date
            FROM `HM_notification` 
                JOIN HM_customers ON HM_customers.id = HM_notification.added_by 
                JOIN HM_products ON HM_products.id = HM_notification.product_id 
                JOIN HM_reviews ON HM_reviews.product_id = HM_notification.product_id 
                WHERE HM_products.user_id=34 AND HM_notification.added_by != 34 AND action_type = 'reviews'

        UNION        

      SELECT 
            HM_notification.product_id,
            HM_products.slug,
            HM_notification.action_type,
            HM_notification.url,
            HM_notification.read_date
            FROM `HM_notification` 
                JOIN HM_customers ON HM_customers.id = HM_notification.added_by 
                JOIN HM_bid ON HM_bid.product_id = HM_notification.product_id 
                JOIN HM_products ON HM_products.id = HM_notification.product_id 
                WHERE HM_products.user_id=34 AND HM_notification.added_by != 34  AND (action_type = 'newbid' OR action_type = 'editbid')

        UNION        

        SELECT 
            HM_notification.product_id,
            HM_products.slug,
            HM_notification.action_type,
            HM_notification.url,
            HM_notification.read_date
            FROM `HM_notification` 
                JOIN HM_customers ON HM_customers.id = HM_notification.added_by 
                JOIN HM_products ON HM_products.id = HM_notification.product_id 
                JOIN HM_order_items ON HM_order_items.product_id = HM_notification.product_id 
                WHERE HM_products.user_id=34 AND HM_notification.added_by != 34 AND (action_type = 'order_pending' OR action_type = 'processing' OR action_type = 'onhold' OR action_type = 'unhold' OR action_type = 'receive' OR action_type = 'addshipment' OR action_type = 'editshipment' OR action_type = 'newcomment' OR action_type = 'addshipmentcomment')

        UNION        

      SELECT 
            HM_notification.product_id,
            HM_products.slug,
            HM_notification.action_type,
            HM_notification.url,
            HM_notification.read_date
            FROM `HM_notification` 
                JOIN HM_customers ON HM_customers.id = HM_notification.added_by 
                JOIN HM_products ON HM_products.id = HM_notification.product_id 
                JOIN HM_conversation ON HM_conversation.pid = HM_notification.product_id 
                WHERE HM_products.user_id=34 AND HM_notification.added_by != 34 AND (HM_conversation.user_one != 34 OR HM_conversation.user_two != 34) AND action_type = 'conversation'
```

Comment: create index for all the tables

Answer (score 1):

since I have not seen your tables,The idea I have now, is that you'd better use 'NATURAL JOIN' instead of 'JOIN' if possible and put your conditions in 'WHERE' part of your query. because the former is faster and more wisely...

hope it helps ...

Answer (score 0):

Use this query.

```
   SELECT 
    n.product_id, 
    p.slug, 
    (case when (p.user_id=9 and n.action_type='product_review') then 'reviews' 
    when (n.action_type='bid_added') then p.slug 
    when (n.action_type='order_processing' OR n.action_type='order_shipped' OR n.action_type='order_onhold' OR n.action_type='order_unhold' OR n.action_type='received') then 'orderlist' 
    when ((con.user_one!=9 OR con.user_two!=9) and n.action_type='chat') then 'messages' end) HM_url
     from HM_notification n, 
          HM_customers c, 
          HM_products p, 
          HM_reviews r, 
          HM_bid b, 
          HM_order_items o, 
          HM_conversation con 
     where  
        n.added_by=c.id 
        and p.id=n.product_id 
        and r.product_id=n.product_id 
        and b.product_id=n.product_id 
        and o.product_id=n.product_id 
        and con.pid=n.product_id 
        and n.added_by != 9;
```